# Amazon Wishlists: Select and Move multiple items at same time from One/ Default Wishlist to others?

Tags: amazon

Amazon Wishlists: Select and Move multiple items at same time from One/ Default Wishlist to others?

Have collected a lot of items on Default Wishlist and would like to MOVE and organize them.

As shown below, one has to select each item one at time from a Default Wishlist to MOVE it to other ones to Organize them.

I was hoping there was some **way to select multiple and have them MOVE together to another list - many at one go**; I am guessing some kind "multi select" using Checkmarks or something else.

Thoughts & ideas welcome.

[image]

Comment: @user67197 - How and when did said feature exist?